# Python - Telethon search (Telegram API for python)

Tags: python, telegram, telethon

**How can I make a text search in a specific channel\chat?**

In the app & web client you can search with a text and date range,

and you will get list of results + counter.

Is there a method I can invoke?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://core.telegram.org/method/messages.search) is probably what you want introduced in layer 12.

```
messages.messages#8c718e87 messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.Messages;
messages.messagesSlice#b446ae3 count:int messages:Vector<Message> chats:Vector<Chat> users:Vector<User> = messages.Messages;
---functions---
messages.search#7e9f2ab peer:InputPeer q:string filter:MessagesFilter min_date:int max_date:int offset:int max_id:int limit:int = messages.Messages;
```